# Lynx colors not applied

Tags: colors, lynx

I have a lynx configuration file in `~/.lynx.cfg`.
To make lynx use it, I have in my environment `$LYNX_CFG` pointing at that file.

Content:

```
# Default
COLOR:0:black:white
# Hyperlinks
COLOR:1:black:white
# Status Line
COLOR:2:black:white
# Emphasis
COLOR:4:black:white
# Hyperlink in em
COLOR:5:black:white
# Selected hyperlink
COLOR:6:black:black
# Search
COLOR:7:black:white

JUSTIFY:TRUE
```

The `JUSTIFY:TRUE` line is correctly applied, but never the `COLOR:*`:

[image]

I'm on OS X Yosemity, in Tmux, using Iterm2, and the lynx version is:

```
Lynx Version 2.8.8rel.2 (09 Mar 2014)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h, ncurses 5.7.20081102
```

What could cause the issue?

Answer (score 1):

That particular set of colors is for the "old" style.   Lynx is built to support one of these:

- a "new" style of color with colors assigned to HTML tag types or
- an "old" style" with colors assigned to links

The "new" style is configured with the [`COLOR_STYLE`](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#COLOR_STYLE) setting in `lynx.cfg`:

> Also known as "lss" (*lynx style-sheet*), the color-style file assigns color combination to tags and combinations of tags. Normally a non-empty value is compiled into `lynx`, and the user can override that using the -lss command-line option. The configure script allows one to compile in an empty string. If `lynx` finds no value for this setting, it simulates the non-color-style assignments using the [**`COLOR`**](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx_help/body.html#COLOR) settings.
>
> If neither the command-line "-lss" or this **`COLOR_STYLE`** setting are given, `lynx tries` the environment variables `"LYNX_LSS"` and `"lynx_lss"`. If neither is set, `lynx` uses the first compiled-in value (which as noted, may be empty).
>
> At startup, `lynx` remembers the name of the color-style file which was used, and together with each file specified, provides those as choices in the ***O**)ptions* menu.

The lynx sources include a script [**`oldlynx`**](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/lynx2.8.8/breakout/samples/oldlynx) which can be used to simulate the old-style:

```
#!/bin/sh
# invoke lynx built with color-style, overriding the color options to use the
# non-color-style scheme -TD

my_cfg=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/lynxcfg$$
trap "rm -f $my_cfg" 0 1 2 5 15

rm -f "$my_cfg"
echo "DEFAULT_COLORS:off" >>$my_cfg
if test -n "$LYNX_CFG" ; then
    echo "include:$LYNX_CFG" >>$my_cfg
fi
echo "COLOR_STYLE:" >>$my_cfg
echo "NESTED_TABLES:off" >>$my_cfg

LYNX_CFG=$my_cfg
export LYNX_CFG
unset LYNX_LSS

${LYNX_PROG-lynx} "$@"
```

For example, here is the help-page with the default color-style:

[image]

and here is the same page using `oldlynx` (using 2.8.7):

[image]

although I just noticed that it does not work for 2.8.8: something overlooked in this [change for 2.8.8dev.17](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.8dev.17):

```
* modify configuration of COLOR_STYLE value in lynx.cfg, allowing multiple
  filenames to be specified and providing those as choices in the O'ptions
  menu (Debian #404893) -TD
```

That made the multiple values for color-style file available as a selection-list in the options menu.  An easy workaround would be to force `lynx` to use an empty color-style *file*, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
# invoke lynx built with color-style, overriding the color options to use the
# non-color-style scheme -TD

my_cfg=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/lynxcfg$$
my_lss=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/lynxlss$$
trap "rm -f $my_lss $my_cfg" 0 1 2 5 15

echo >$my_lss

rm -f "$my_cfg"
echo "DEFAULT_COLORS:off" >>$my_cfg
if test -n "$LYNX_CFG" ; then
        echo "include:$LYNX_CFG" >>$my_cfg
fi
echo "COLOR_STYLE:" >>$my_cfg
echo "NESTED_TABLES:off" >>$my_cfg

LYNX_CFG=$my_cfg
export LYNX_CFG
LYNX_LSS=$my_lss
export LYNX_LSS

${LYNX_PROG-lynx} "$@"
```

(some might use `mktemp`, but when the script was written that was less topical than now).

Comment: Nice, does this mean that I need an external `lss` file anyway? (I must admit I would have prefered setting all in the `lynx.cfg` file)

Comment: On the command-line, the filename can be an empty string.  Doing that makes `lynx` use the `COLOR` settings.

Comment: I see, in the meantime I've created a lss file and linked in the config file, but it does not seem to apply to lynx. What can you suggest me to check if the lss file is actually used ?

Comment: You can use the `-trace` option with `-trace-mask=10` , and see the definitions which are used in `$HOME/Lynx.trace`

Comment: Apparently, the `~/.lynx.lss` is correctly used with `add_to_lss_list`, but only the pre-installed lynx.lss (`/usr/local/Cellar/lynx/2.8.8rel.2_1/etc/lynx.lss`) is opened and read... I still have the `~/.lynx.lss` on the option page, but when I select it, instead of having the new colors, the selected lss file became `OFF`...